# How to add suffix and preffix for radios field in drupal?

Tags: theming

This is my code. And is it right way to add suffix and preffix to a radios?

```
    $form['option_' . $question_count_flag] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#options' => $qt_options,
      '#prefix' => '',
      '#suffix' => '', 
    );
```

Here $qtn_options is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. When you add a prefix/suffix, the whole field will come before/after your markup.

You can use the prefix/suffix attributes to wrap the whole field in a container; here's an example:

```
$form['option_' . $question_count_flag] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => $qt_options,
  '#prefix' => '<div id="radio-wrapper">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>', 
);
```

The output you would get is:

```
<div id="radio-wrapper">
  // Regular form item markup with your radio options will go here.
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. If this is what you were looking for, mark this post as the answer so it helps others with the same question.